# Excel VBA StrCmp sub or function not defined when used different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba, I want to compare two string from different sheets using strcomp.

I tried following syntax, but it shows error.

```
com = StrComp(Year, worksheets(newsheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "Year" without a date

```
com = StrComp(Year(date), worksheets(newsheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1)).Value)
```